# Kata help. String formating seems fine to me

Tags: java, string

So I'm trying the second Java code wars kata, but the string formater is returning the proper things when I test it. Here's the kata:

```
public class Person {
  String name;

    public Person(String personName) {
            name = personName;
    }

    public String greet(String yourName) {
            return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
    }
}
```

My attempt:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Person p = new Person("bob");
        System.out.println(p.greet("bobby"));
     }
}

class Person {
  String name;

    public Person(String personName) {
            name = personName;
    }

    public String greet(String yourName) {
            return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
    }
}
```

It should work just fine, what's wrong? I'm doing [this site's kata](http://www.codewars.com/), and I'm not sure what it needs.

Comment: What do you mean by "what's wrong"? What makes you think something *is* wrong?

Comment: `String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName)` ... this is like *"Hi 'myName', my name is 'yourName'"*. But why is my name like your name and not like my name? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have reversed the order of the arguments in the `greet` method:

```
public String greet(String yourName) {
    return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name);
}
```